# Issues importing data from Yahoo using quantmod package

Tags: r, quantmod

```
library(quantmod)
startDate = as.Date("2010-01-04")
endDate = as.Date("2015-01-08")
getSymbols("CAT", from=startDate,to=endDate)
```

I am using R version 3.2.3.

I have error as below:

> ```
> trying URL 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY&a=0&b=01&c=2007&d=2&e=16&f=2018&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=SPY&x=.csv'
> Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m, :
> cannot open URL 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY&a=0&b=01&c=2007&d=2&e=16&f=2018&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=SPY&x=.csv'
> In addition: Warning message:
> In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m, :
> InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
> ```

Comment: Your code works absolutely fine for me. Btw, latest R version is 3.4.4 (2018-03-15).

Comment: platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.3                         
year           2015                        
month          12                          
day            10                          
svn rev        69752                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)

Comment: You need to upgrade to the latest version of quantmod on CRAN. This is a bug that has been fixed.